# Accepting Splunk license agreement using Ansible-Playbook

Tags: ansible, splunk

I am new to using Ansible-Playbooks, and I am running into issues in accepting license agreements with Splunk.

Any time I have shell run:

```
"/opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start --accept-license --answer-yes"
```

I get a continuous lockup that forces me to terminate the program.

```
TASK [acceptlicense] ****************************************************************************************************************

^C
```

Going into the box and running the command manually I am told the following:

```
[root@##########-lab_env]# /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start --accept-license --answer-yes

This appears to be your first time running this version of Splunk.

Create credentials for the administrator account.
Characters do not appear on the screen when you type the password.
Password must contain at least:
   * 8 total printable ASCII character(s).
Please enter a new password:
```

I have gone through several forums online that give help in answering what to do when met with specific prompts like this, but anytime I make an adjustment I am told something along the lines of:

> ERROR! '_______' is not a valid attribute for a Task

At this point I am pretty stuck and unsure of how to continue.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
- hosts: "{{hostName}}"
  become: true
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo

  tasks: 

    - name: copy_splunk
      shell: cp splunkforwarder-7.1.3-51d9cac7b837-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm /opt/.; date; ls -l /opt
      args:
        chdir: /tmp
      register: run_ll

    - debug: var=run_ll.stdout_lines

    - name: install rpm package
      shell: rpm -ivh splunkforwarder-7.1.3-51d9cac7b837-linux-2.6-x86_64.rpm
      args:
        chdir: /tmp
      ignore_errors: True
      register: install_rpm

    - debug: var=install_rpm.stdout_lines

    - name: acceptlicense
      tags:
        - install
      shell: /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk start --accept-license --answer-yes
      register: accept_l

    - debug: var=accept_l.stdout_lines
```

I have only done a couple of playbooks in the past, so this error is something new to me.

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not well documented by Splunk, but there are two ways to do that.

1) Provide the password on the command line.  `splunk start --accept-license --answer-yes --no-prompt --seed-passwd <passwd>`.

2) Create a $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf file

```
[user_info]
USERNAME = admin
PASSWORD = <password>
```

Then start Splunk:
`splunk start --accept-license --answer-yes --no-prompt`

Comment: Success! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [expect module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/expect_module.html). It will allow you to execute commands and respond to their respective prompts.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/splunk-forwarder-installation-using-ansible/) of how to use the expect module. This method kept timing out for me and did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Building on RichG's answer, here are the Ansible tasks I used to make this work.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: create a random password
      ansible.builtin.shell: date +%s | sha256sum | base64 | head -c 32 ; echo
      register: _splunk_password
      changed_when: false

    - name: hash the random password
      ansible.builtin.command:
        argv:
          - /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk
          - "hash-passwd"
          - "{{ _splunk_password.stdout }}"
      register: _splunk_hashed_password
      changed_when: false

    - name: create the user-seed config file
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: user-seed.conf.j2
        dest: /opt/splunkforwarder/etc/system/local/user-seed.conf
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0640
      become: yes

    - name: accept the license
      ansible.builtin.shell:
        argv:
          - /opt/splunkforwarder/bin/splunk
          - start
          - "--accept-license"
          - "--answer-yes"
          - "--no-prompt"
      become: yes
```

And the user-seed.conf.j2 file looks as follows:

```
#
# {{ ansible_managed }}
#

[user_info]
USERNAME = admin
HASHED_PASSWORD = {{ _splunk_hashed_password.stdout }}
```